# Polymorphic behavior in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have following java code,

```
interface A {
    int a = 5;
}

class B {
    int a = 6;
}

public class C extends B implements A {
    int b = super.a;//Line 10
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println(new C().b);//6

    }
}
```

I was expecting compiler error at line 10 because compiler will not know which "a" to refer. But there was no compiler error. Output is 6. Can someone explain  how it takes class B 's instance variable value(6) why not interface A's "a" value which is 5?.

Comment: Just because *you* don't know which variable the `a` is referring to, that doesn't mean the compiler doesn't either :)

Comment: all fields defined in interface are Constancts i.e. static and final. Whereas the `a` deined by class `B` is instance field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` keyword is used to refer to the parent class which in this case is `B`. Hence you get output as `6`.

`a` defined in `interface A` is static and `a` defined in `Class B` is an instance variable. Hence when we do `super.a`, it refers to the instance value of `a` which is defined in the `Class B`

If you rename the variable in `B` say as `aa`, you will get compiler error saying `a cannot be resolved or is not a field` because `a` defined in `interface A` is not directly accessible in `class C`, because it is by default `static`. To access `a` defined in `interface A`, we need to make an explicit call to `A.a` in class `C`

If you define, `a` as static in `class B`, and remove `super`, you will get `compiler error: The field a is ambiguous`